# Fitting text in div after substitution

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following JavaScript:

```
var answer = prompt('what is input', ' ');

$('.words').text(answer);
```

Which prompts for some text input then replaces text already in a div styled with .words that already has a fixed width and length.  The div aligns text in the center but if the user puts in too many words the text will flow out of the div, which is bordered, and looks bad.  Also if the user puts in too few words, there will be a lot of empty space in the div. Is there a script I can insert that will shrink the font size to accommodate the extra text or expand the font size to better fit the text in the div if there is not much of it entered by the user.  Thanks

Comment: use $('.words').html(answer);

Answer (score 1):

```
var answer = prompt('what is input', ' ');
$('.words').html(answer);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qbrmp/)

Comment: that doesnt do it.  Things remain the same.  I should add .words is a div within another div called .picture  the css for each is

Comment: .picture {width:640px; height:480px; background-image:url(/users/skronwith/desktop/sig.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center}
.words {position:absolute;width:320px; height:240px;padding:20px;border:10px;border-color:red;border-style:solid;text-align:center;font-size: 40px; line-height:1.2em;margin-left:140px;margin-top:110px}